# My facebook actions have been approved but are only posting to a tester's timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My facebook actions have been approved by facebook but for some reason are still only posting to timelines of my testing accounts... is there any reason that this would be?... please note that the actions are not even appearing on the activity log of non testing users... the activity log should catch every action that gets posted to it... whether that makes it to the timeline is another matter but it should at least appear in the activity log... kind regards to any responders.

Comment: What errors are you getting when posting the actions? Have your non-test users granted publish_actions permission?

Comment: Thanks Igy... I was using the wrong access_token... what an idiot... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have forgotten some emails and passwords hardcoded somewhere.

Comment: Yep, using the wrong access_token... what an idiot... thanks.